# Failed updating EF 6 DbContex using EntityState.Modified

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an airport entity who has reference to another entities which every entity has her own references.

while trying to update the airport, i've got some exceptions..
heres the code trying to update the airport

```
var airport = context.Airports
    .Where(a => a.AirportID == airportToUpdate.AirportID).FirstOrDefault();

var ai = AirportConverter.ToModel(airportToUpdate);
ai.AirportID = airport.AirportID;
airport.IsOpenForFlights = ai.IsOpenForFlights;

airport.EmergencyLandings = new List<Scenario>();
foreach (var emergency in ai.EmergencyLandings)
{
    var sce = context.Scenarios
        .Include(s => s.Mission).Include(s => s.Planes)
        .Where(s => s.ScenarioID == emergency.ScenarioID).First();
    airport.EmergencyLandings.Add(sce);
    context.Entry(sce).State = EntityState.Modified;
}

airport.ExistingFilghtNumbers = new List<string>();
foreach (var flight in ai.ExistingFilghtNumbers)
{
    airport.ExistingFilghtNumbers.Add(flight);
    context.Entry(flight).State = EntityState.Modified;
}

var parkingLot = ai.ParkingLots.First();
var pLot = context.ParkingLots
    .Include(p => p.AtAirport)
    .Include(p => p.ParkingStations.Select(pa => pa.PlaneParking))
    .Where(p => p.ParkingLotID == parkingLot.ParkingLotID).First();
airport.ParkingLots = new List<ParkingLot>();
airport.ParkingLots.Add(pLot);
context.Entry(pLot).State = EntityState.Modified;

airport.Queues = new List<PlanesQueue>();
foreach (var queue in ai.Queues)
{
    qu = context.PlanesQueues
        .Include(p => p.Planes.Select(pl => pl.AtQueue))
        .Where(q => q.QueueNumber == queue.QueueNumber).First();
    qu.Planes = queue.Planes;
    airport.Queues.Add(qu);
    context.Entry(qu).State = EntityState.Modified;
}

airport.Routes = new List<Route>();
foreach (var route in ai.Routes)
{
    var ro = context.Routes
        .Include(r => r.PlaneOnRoute)
        .Where(r => r.RouteID == route.RouteID).First();
    airport.Routes.Add(route);
    context.Entry(route).State = EntityState.Modified;
}

//var entry = context.Entry(airport);
//entry.State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
context.SaveChanges();
```

i've already tried the simplest update until i've got to this code..
tried to remove the entity first and then add it again and tried to update every entity before updating the airport itself.

and it still doesn't work, many exceptions like

> Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type 'FlightsControl.Dal.Entities.Route' have the same primary key value. Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are unique. Ensure that database-generated primary keys are configured correctly in the database and in the Entity Framework model. Use the Entity Designer for Database First/Model First configuration. Use the 'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption" fluent API or 'DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' for Code First configuration

of course it will has the same primary key, i'm trying to update this and not just to add it..

**this is the airport entity**

```
public virtual int AirportID { get; set; }
public  ICollection<PlanesQueue> Queues { get; set; }
public  ICollection<ParkingLot> ParkingLots { get; set; }
public  ICollection<Route> Routes { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<string> ExistingFilghtNumbers { get; set; }
public virtual bool IsOpenForFlights { get; set; }
public  ICollection<Scenario> EmergencyLandings { get; set; }
```

**airport config**

```
public AirportConfig()
{
    this.HasKey(a => a.AirportID);
    this.Property(a => a.AirportID)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    this.HasMany(a => a.Queues).WithRequired(q => q.AtAirport);
    this.HasMany(a => a.ParkingLots).WithRequired(p => p.AtAirport);
    this.HasMany(a => a.Routes).WithRequired(r => r.AtAirport);
    this.HasMany(a => a.EmergencyLandings).WithRequired(s => s.AtAirport);
}
```

Comment: Well, on the specific case of Route, you are querying and returning it to the a variable in `var ro = context.Routes.Include(r => r.PlaneOnRoute).Where(r => r.RouteID == route.RouteID).First();`, but are using another entity to add and flag as modified on the model in `context.Entry(route).State = EntityState.Modified;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are querying on the context for the Route, but the one you're adding to the list and flagging as modified is the one entity fetched on the loop.
Try using that Route you queried instead of the other one, like you did in all other cases. Like:

```
airport.Routes = new List<Route>();
foreach (var route in ai.Routes)
{
    var ro = context.Routes
      .Include(r => r.PlaneOnRoute)
      .First(r => r.RouteID == route.RouteID); 
    airport.Routes.Add(ro);
    context.Entry(ro).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

And just a little note: Linq's `First` method has a version that accepts a predicate as parameter, so you could write `context.Routes.Include(r => r.PlaneOnRoute).First(r => r.RouteID == route.RouteID);` for brevity, like I did on my code sample.

Comment: still, it throws me the same exception, the thing is that i want the `route` in `ai.Routes` will be aded to the airport because it is the newest

Comment: What DB are you using? I can try to repro that later on.

Comment: Made it.. i didn't notice i'm trying to update the `route` and not the `ro`